# Wordpress Elementor missing linebreaks

Tags: wordpress, elementor

The problem is related to switching between wordpress original editor and the elementor editor.

The problems appears after you have made an edit with the ordinary wordpress editor, when the page was created/edited in the elementor editor.

After this edit, if you visit the published page, all line breaks have disappeared.

The absurd thing is that if you go into the elementor editor (to fix and reinsert the missing line breaks ), they are actually there already and seen in both the Elementor Viual view, as well as in the Text view AND in the preview window.

The only rescue is to either recreate the sections from scratch, or go back to the previous version of the page.

[image: The look of generated HTML on a problematic page, red lines symbolize where line breaks used to be]